# Updating the list of online users when closing the webpage without logging out of an Asp.Net MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, arraylist

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC application in which I have a feature which shows the list of online users. I used a `LIST` to add a user to it whenever he logs into the application and remove him from the `LIST` whenever he logs out of application by clicking the `LogOut` button.

I have the following code in my `AccountController`  in `Login ActionResult`

```
 if (HttpRuntime.Cache["LoggedInUsers"] != null)
                {
                    List<string> loggedInUsers = (List<string>)HttpRuntime.Cache["LoggedInUsers"];
                    //add this user to the list
                    if (loggedInUsers.Contains(model.UserName))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loggedInUsers.Add(model.UserName);
                        HttpRuntime.Cache["LoggedInUsers"] = loggedInUsers;
                    }
                }
                else //the list does not exist so create it
                {
                    //create a new list
                    List<string> loggedInUsers = new List<string>();
                    //add this user to the list
                    if (loggedInUsers.Contains(model.UserName))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loggedInUsers.Add(model.UserName);
                        HttpRuntime.Cache["LoggedInUsers"] = loggedInUsers;
                    }

                }
```

Also, I have the following code in `LogOff ActionResult`

```
string username = User.Identity.Name; //get the users username who is logged in
            if (HttpRuntime.Cache["LoggedInUsers"] != null)//check if the list has been created
            {
                // HttpRuntime.Cache["LoggedInUsers"] = null;
                //the list is not null so we retrieve it from the cache
                List<string> loggedInUsers = (List<string>)HttpRuntime.Cache["LoggedInUsers"];
                if (loggedInUsers.Contains(username))//if the user is in the list
                {
                    //then remove them
                    loggedInUsers.Remove(username);
                }
                // else do nothing
            }
```

But, I do want to take the user out of the `LIST` if he just closes the application without clicking on `LogOff` Button and add him back when he opens the application again.

Is there any good way to do it.

Comment: There is no message that gets sent to the server when a user closes their browser. There may be a JavaScript event that fires which you could hook into and send an AJAX request to the server that removes the user.

Comment: Thanks but I am not a JS Expert.

Comment: Some browsers have an event that fires when the page is closed, but you cannot rely on that. The common approach is implementing a timeout for your cache, so when there's no actions from the user for some time, he is considered "inactive", and removed from user list.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub I can try that, but is it possible to add him back to the list if comes back active onto that page?

Comment: Sure you can. Generally, you shouldn't distinguish if the user returned to the page after some inactivity time, or reopened the page in a few days from another computer. When there's an activity from the user, you check if he is already in the active users list. If he is, you just update the "last seen" timestamp, otherwise you add a new entry. When displaying the list of active users, filter those entries whose "last seen" timestamp is not too old (15 minutes is okay, I believe).

Comment: Also I've noticed you're not doing any thread synchronization in your code. Web Server is operating in multiple threads, so synchronizing access to cache is a must. Also you would lose your list if web server restarts for some reason. Why don't you store a last activity timestamp for each user in the database?